# Convert VB6 .dll file to a .net dll

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies

I have a .dll file written in VB6. I understand that I can add this .dll file as a reference in my VS project, but I need to be able to add this .dll file as an embedded resource to my VS solution. I then would like to invoke this .dll file to call a function.

However I cannot load the .dll file as an assembly because it was written in VB6. Assuming I cannot simply rewrite this code to .net, does anyone have a working solution for converting this dll to a recognizable assembly file?

Comment: If you're still talking about the same DLL you asked about in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654313/using-a-vb6-dll-in-net), then I don't think what you're asking is truly possible.  The code you're talking about calls Win32 functions to perform unsafe native memory operations, and it only fails because of an access violation.  It may not be possible to perform those memory manipulations in a managed-memory environment.

Comment: The dll works just fine. I'm just trying to get it to work with CodeDom now

Answer (score 5):

You won't need to convert it, you just need to reference it as an unmanaged DLL.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301501.aspx for instructions on how to do this.

Comment: Harvery I understand now that I need to reference the code as unmanaged. However, I'm still confused as to how I should go about adding the dll to my .Net project. Through Visual Studio I could simply add the .dll file as a reference, however, when using CodeDom I am not able to simply add the .dll as a reference. So, that is why I was converting in the first place. I need to be able to add this dll to my CodeDom generated file!

Comment: To get early binding (i.e. the ability to add a reference to your DLL in Visual Studio), you will most likely need to convert your DLL to an ActiveX DLL.  More info here: http://www.csharp-station.com/Articles/CSharpAndActiveXDlls.aspx

Comment: I already have no problem adding this COM dll to VS and referencing it. The problem only occurs when I try to add it a a reference via CodeDom.

Comment: Why don't you try wrapping your COM DLL in a managed DLL?  I assume you can load managed DLL's via CodeDom without problems.

Comment: I read about that but I could not figure out how to get it to work. Something about GcHandle() - does this sound correct?